# Display a div on pageload

Tags: javascript, html

I am passing div name in the query string from one html page and retrieving that div name on the other html page. Now I want to display that specific div on the page.My code is

```
function onLoad()
{    
    var divname=window.location.search.substring(1);    
    document.getElementById(divname).style.display="block";    //error is in this line
}
```

But I am getting an error as "object expected". please help me

Comment: Please do put code inside a code-block so it's much easier to read and for us to help.
edit: thanks.

Comment: What's the value of the `divname` variable? Do you have corresponding element with such id?

Comment: divname is variable which holds value of the div name which I want to display

Comment: Yes, and what's its value? `alert(divname);`?

Comment: Log the count of elements that match your divname  to make sure it is finding it correctly.  `console.log(document.getElementByID(divname0).length);` .  Your error  is indicating that it cannot apply the style.display to a null object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-written my function and it is working, code is like this

```
function load()  
{  
    var divname = window.location.search.substring(1);  
    var params=divname.split('=');  
    var i=1;  
    alert(params[i].substring(0));  
    document.getElementById(params[i].substring(0)).style.display='block';  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) property returns the part of the URL that follows the `?` symbol, including the `?` symbol.

So for example it might return `?paramname=paramvalue`. When you call `substring(1)` on it you get `paramname=paramvalue` which is what gets passed to the `document.getElementById` function which obviously is wrong because such element does doesn't exist on your DOM.

You could use the [`following javascript function`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/29407) to read query string parameter values:

```
function onLoad() {    
    var divname = getParameterByName('divname');    
    document.getElementById(divname).style.display = 'block';
}
```

This assumes that you have a query string parameter name called `divname`:

```
?divname=some_div_name
```

Adjust the parameter passed to the `getParameterByName` function if your query string parameter is called differently.

You might also want to introduce error checking into your code to make it more robust:

```
function onLoad() {    
    var divname = getParameterByName('divname');    
    var divElement = document.getElementById(divname);
    if (divElement != null) {
        divElement.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        alert('Unable to find an element with name = ' + divname);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have copied this code as it is but I am getting an error on line no 2 in "onLoad()" function, it says "object expected"

Comment: Did you declare the `getParameterByName` function? I have linked to it in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values/901144#901144 Make sure that this function is declared before using it.

Answer (score 0):

What I am suggesting is place your `js` at the end of the `html` code (before `</body>` tag). Do not use a function.

```
<html>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <body>
    ...
    ...
    ...
        <script>
            var divname=window.location.search.substring(1);    
            document.getElementById(divname).style.display="block"; 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```